# PHP cURL total_time slow with multiple requests

Tags: php, curl

I am running multiple cURL requests serially from PHP. My code to run the requests looks like:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: application/json')
);
curl_exec($ch);
error_log("curl info: " . print_r(curl_getinfo($ch), true));
curl_close($ch);
```

Everything works fine with the first request. The data from `curl_getinfo` looks like this:

```
[url] => http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
[http_code] => 201
[header_size] => 492
[request_size] => 145
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.336019
[namelookup_time] => 0.140008
[connect_time] => 0.17601
[pretransfer_time] => 0.17601
[size_upload] => 2632
[size_download] => 178
[speed_download] => 529
[speed_upload] => 7832
[download_content_length] => 178
[upload_content_length] => 2632
[starttransfer_time] => 0.212012
[redirect_time] => 0
```

However, the second request takes about three seconds. This is reflected in `total_time`, but all of the individual time values are small:

```
[url] => http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
[http_code] => 201
[header_size] => 492
[request_size] => 145
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 3.572204
[namelookup_time] => 0
[connect_time] => 0.036002
[pretransfer_time] => 0.036002
[size_upload] => 2632
[size_download] => 178
[speed_download] => 49
[speed_upload] => 736
[download_content_length] => 178
[upload_content_length] => 2632
[starttransfer_time] => 0.068004
[redirect_time] => 0
```

What is causing `total_time` to be so long even though connecting and transferring happen quickly? I also logged the timing of this request on the server (using error_log and PHP) and it is not seeing the beginning of the request until 3 seconds after I call curl_exec on the client. Here is my PHP and cURL version information from the client:

```
$php -v
PHP 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.14 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Jan 12 2011 15:54:52)
$curl -V
curl 7.18.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.18.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8g zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.1
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

Comment: If I can't solve this them I'm just going to implement the requests using PHP sockets, but I was hoping for an easier solution.

Comment: could be a config problem at your machine. try posting to your website from any online curl tool like http://www.dekho-ji.com/website-diagnostics-curl-http-request-response-headers-online and see if it gives same delay/lag. check request/response headers from curl, HEADER_OUT = true